# Ajax is not working correctly in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i like to explain my issue with example. I have 2 fields FromDate ,ToDate and one button in my view. if i select the FromDate ,ToDate and click the button means it want to display the data in the same view based on  Date Selection which  is mentioned in the below image.

[My main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuGCp.jpg)

**My View Model (VisitorsViewModel)**

```
    public DateTime  ? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime  ? ToDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<View_VisitorsForm> Visits { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
   public ActionResult DailyVisitReport()
  {
     return View();
  } 
  public ActionResult GetDatesfromFromDateToDate(string fromDate, string toDate)
    {
        DateTime fromdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
        DateTime todt = Convert.ToDateTime(toDate);
        List<View_VisitorsForm> VisitCount = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm
                                         where v.VisitingDate >= fromdt && v.VisitingDate <= todt
                                         select v).ToList();

        VisitorsViewModel visitotsVM = new VisitorsViewModel();
        visitotsVM.Visits= VisitCount;
        return PartialView("_Visitors", visitotsVM);
    }
```

Here i got the From Date and To Date Value and list the data using query as per FromDate and ToDate Criteria and passed to partial view

**MY partial view Coding**

```
 @model Sample_Customer.Models.VisitorsViewModel
 @foreach (var item in Model.Visits)
 {
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.VisitingDate)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Employee)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.CustomerName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.POVisit)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.ContactPerson)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.NextAppointment)</td>

     </tr>
 }
```

**My View**

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" }) 
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Ok" />
```

**My j query code**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#FromDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
    $("#ToDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
    });
  </script>


  $('#Button1').click(function () {
    debugger;
    alert("hhh");
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetDatesfromFromDateToDate", "Report")', {
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: {
                fromDate: $("#FromDate").val(), toDate: $("#ToDate").val()
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {

                var div = $("#visitors");
                div.empty();
                div.html(data);
            }
          });
       });
```

Now it pass the date to controller and it calculate the list from partial view as per that criteria . Up to this it is working fine but it wont displaying the data. see the below image . it getting the data  and it is visible in network . But it not displaying the data. it showing fail to retrieve alert box.

[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VJnX.jpg)

Please any one tell me the solution to resolve this issue . I tried my level best to explain my issue .please any one understand and give me the solution.please any one check my j query success function code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `html` not `json`. Change this line:

```
dataType: "json"
```

to

```
dataType: "html",
```

Also this is deprecated way of doing `ajax` in jQuery. Try this:

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDatesfromFromDateToDate", "Report")',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    data: {
        fromDate: $("#FromDate").val(), toDate: $("#ToDate").val()
    },
}).done(function (data) {
    var div = $("#visitors");
    div.empty();
    div.html(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: No gzaxx its not working it showing fail to retrieve alert message after change to datatype : "html" but it getting the data and it is visblle in network element

Comment: Can you give what exception message it gives you?

Comment: ya sure give me 2 mins time

Comment: [Fail][3]
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h5HyP.jpg  this is the message iam getting and in console it showing one warning. that's it gzaxx.

Comment: I edited my answer, please use my code piece and paste text status if error still occurs.

Comment: gzaxx i got the output thanks alott. but  one doubt why you saying this code is deprecated code. May i know the reason and let me know if any problem will come  in future. :)

Comment: @Susan please take a look at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation